# Stack Overflow paging doesn't return full set

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

When 50 is selected as the page size on Stack Overflow it only returns 49 results.

The easiest way to test this is to simply open up a console and use `$('.question-summary').length`, although I also used several methods to double and triple check including manually counting each question.

[image]

It should either say 49, or return 50.

Comment: [Mine shows 50.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iOZPQ.png) Maybe it caches them and then removes deleted ones? Have you tried reproducing it in multiple browsers?

Comment: @Stryner - It is possible that this is the result of cached deleted questions. The browser did not effect the results though.

Comment: It's consistently 49, even if the page contents change or you're logged out.

Comment: Chrome bug maybe? I don't see this with Firefox 45 or Opera 35.

Comment: There is also the possibility it was fixed since posting this report @ArtjomB. At this time I am unable to reproduce returning 49. Will keep an eye on it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question lists are cached for short periods of time to improve performance. If a question ends up deleted, it gets removed from the list for that page and it will simply show fewer items on the page until that particular list gets recached to update it. Once recached, each page should show 50 items again.